# Python: Using defined arguments with *args

Tags: python, python-2.7, args

Rewritten to make more clear the use-case and answer better Anentropic's question.

```
def use_all (step_todo, wait_complete=True, *args):
    execute_step1 (step-todo)
    handle_args (*args)
    if not wait_complete: 
       do_somehing ()
       return
    execute_stepN ()

@decorate
def use_from (step_todo, *args):
    use_all (step_todo, args)

@decorate
def use_many ():
    use_all (step_todo1, wait_complete=False)
    use_all (step_todo2, args2)
    use_all (step_todo3)
```

The `use_all` is the main "executive" to process the steps (exactly`pxssh` for installation). It *shall not* be *decorated* with start/stop comments as may be called several times from a procedure (e.g. `step_many` which is reboot - reason for no `wait_complete`), but single step *shall* be.

As the use-case is specific, I may see solution to handle the `*args` as _single named variable containing tuple, e.g.

```
def use_all (step_todo, wait_complete=True, args_list=()):
```

Is this correct (and recommended) solution?

This is somehow linked to questions [python function *args and **kwargs with other specified keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003939/python-function-args-and-kwargs-with-other-specified-keyword-arguments) or [Using default arguments before positional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332195/using-default-arguments-before-positional-arguments/12332626#12332626) . Is it possible *not* to parse `kwargs` and *keep* Python R2.7?

Thanks
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
def use_from(step_todo, *args):
    use_all(step_todo, *args)
```

...otherwise you are calling `use_all` with a single arg containing a list of values, instead of calling it with the multiple args

also, don't put a space between your function and the parentheses, it's bad style :)

to get around the problem of `wait_complete` taking value of your first arg you need to pass it explicitly, eg:

```
def use_from(step_todo, *args):
    use_all(step_todo, True, *args)
```

Comment: Good points, both of them, but this still doesn't fix the problem of wait_complete taking the first args value.

Comment: yes, because of this you will always have to explicitly pass a value for `wait_complete`

Comment: wait_complete eats up the first arg, you could call it like this `use_all(step_todo, True, *args)`, but that is just plain ugly, I think use_all()'s parameter list needs to be reworked.

Comment: yep, so essentially the answer to the OP is "it's not possible to do that in python 2.7"

Comment: I don't see the point of the `use_all` function, perhaps with a more complete example we could suggest a useful alternative

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible to do in Python 2.7, however in python 3.x you could:

```
def use_all (step_todo, *args, wait_complete=True):
    print('W_C: {0}'.format(wait_complete))
    print('Args: {0}'.format(args))

def use_from (step_todo, *args, **kwargs):
    use_all (step_todo, *args, **kwargs)

use_from ('Step1')
use_from ('Step3', 'aa:bb:cc')
```

Ouput:

```
>>> W_C: True
>>> Args: ()
>>> W_C: True
>>> Args: ('aa:bb:cc',)
```